# making format specifier by parsing strings with preprocessor

Tags: c, parsing, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to make a variable format specifier this way?

```
#define TOST(i) #i   //to string

printf("str: %" TOST(5) "s \n", "abcdefgh");
```

when it compiles, it ignores the number.
if not this way, still, i would like to know how to make a variable format specifier.

Comment: Try using a larger number like 15.

Comment: it wont be much variable becouse arg cant be a variable

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of `%.*d`

Comment: ok, i get it. thx!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Your code compiles correctly, producing a format string of `"str: %5s \n"`.

However, note that the expected behavior of `printf` is that it will print the entire string even if the string exceeds the width you specify in the format string.

Comment: No, it also applies to numbers.  Why ask here when you can just try it out yourself with a few quick lines of code?  `printf("%2d\n", 999);`

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` specifier has two fields, `width.precision`.
Width will print at least the indicated characters `%5s`. Positive widths are right justified. Negative widths are left justified. If there more characters, the output is expanded as needed.
Precision will print no more than the indicated characters `%.5s`.
`%10.5s` would print no more than 5 characters in a field 10 characters wide.

`#define TOST(i) #i` can be used to insert a integer constant into a string.

A pair of `#define`'s can be used to stringify defined constants.

`printf` will allow an asterisk to insert an integer value into the format string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOST(i) #i   //to string

#define WIDTH 15
#define PRECISION 5
//stringify
#define SFS(x) #x
#define FS(x) SFS(x)

int main ( void) {
    printf("str TOST(15):  [%" TOST(15) "s]\n", "abcdefgh");
    printf("str -TOST(15): [%-" TOST(15) "s]\n", "abcdefgh");
    printf("str .TOST(5):  [%." TOST(5) "s]\n", "abcdefgh");

    printf("str FS(WIDTH):      [%" FS(WIDTH) "s]\n", "abcdefgh");
    printf("str -FS(WIDTH):     [%-" FS(WIDTH) "s]\n", "abcdefgh");
    printf("str .FS(PRECISION): [%." FS(PRECISION) "s]\n", "abcdefgh");

    int limit = 15;
    printf("str int limit = 15:  [%*s]\n", limit, "abcdefgh");
    printf("str -int limit = 15: [%-*s]\n", limit, "abcdefgh");
    limit = 5;
    printf("str .int limit = 5:  [%.*s]\n", limit, "abcdefgh");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of a field is the *minimum* field width, not maximum. The string is longer than 5, so minimum is ignored.

While it is possible with preprocessor, why use it. Just use:

```
printf("str: %.*s \n", 5, "abcdefgh");
```